# Newtonsoft.JSON serialize object? property as .NET type

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following model:

```cs
public class Event
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreationDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

    [StringLength(64)]
    public string AuthorEmail { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// When this event was generated
    /// </summary>
    public DateTimeOffset EventDateTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Type of event, determines the type of the <see cref="Data"/>
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(32)] public string Type { get; set; } = null!;
    [StringLength(32)] public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    [StringLength(128)] public string? Description { get; set; }
    public LogLevel Level { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event data, like links, attachments, the product for example a product event and more.
    /// </summary>
    public object? Data { get; set; }

    public List<OPGEventTag> Tags { get; set; } = new();
}
```

When i set `public object? Data { get; set; }` to an object, for example:

```cs
evt.Data = newServerVersionData()
{
    Version = version ?? "err no version!!!",
    VersionPrevious = versionPrevious
}

...

var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(events, Formatting.None,
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            }
```

I get the following output:

```json
{
      "$type": "[REDACTED].Event, [REDACTED]",
      "Id": "b1f6b5b0-d6b7-4737-6409-08db2207c94a",
      "CreationDateTime": "2023-03-11T08:08:23.9580219+00:00",
      "ModifiedDateTime": "2023-03-11T08:08:23.9581946+00:00",
      "AuthorEmail": "[REDACTED]",
      "EventDateTime": "2023-03-11T08:08:23.9582796+00:00",
      "Type": "ServerVersion",
      "Title": "Server update 0.0.0.0 => 1.0.0",
      "Description": null,
      "Level": 2,
      "Data": {
        "versionPrevious": "0.0.0.0",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      },
```

As we can see, type information is persisted, but not for `Data`, presumably because it is an `object?`.

How can i make it so type information is kept for properties with type `object` so that i can deserialize the json to the actual type?

Comment: `object` has no meaningful properties to serialize.  Using a property of type `object` implies very loose typing, perhaps you want to use a generic property instead?  (So a class of `Event<T>` with a property of `public T? Data { get; set; }` ?)

Comment: @David I have overrides for more specific events, but i need to also serialize generic ones, hence i save `Event` not `Event<T>`. In both cases anyhow i need to serialize the correct type information. So yes the typing is loose, but thats in line with my use-case.

Comment: If you're stuck with using `object` then you may need to create a custom serializer for your class which gets runtime type information from the property and serializes the properties from that type.  By default Newtonsoft is only going to serialize the type it's given, which in this case has no properties.

Comment: @David that sounds like it makes sense. Do you have a sample on how to do this or more information to get me on track?

Comment: It's been ages since I've done a custom serializer, and even then it was just for minor tweaks.  But Googling "newtonsoft json custom serializer" led me [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) (and of course [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm)), as well as to [some Stack Overflow questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=newtonsoft+json+custom+serializer+site:stackoverflow.com) that look helpful.

Comment: I imagine you'd want to start with a proof-of-concept that uses a custom serializer which doesn't actually do anything custom, just works as-is with default behavior.  Then within the code of that (otherwise empty) custom serializer you'd start debugging and see if you can pick out runtime information from your `Data` property to output to the serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by using the following custom type converter:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Converts object properties to their runtime type with type information.
/// Ensure <c>TypeNameHandling</c> is set to <c>TypeNameHandling.All</c>
/// </summary>
public class RuntimeTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    #region Overrides of JsonConverter

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(object);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

```cs
// object
[JsonConverter(typeof(RuntimeTypeConverter))]
object? Data { get; set; }

// setting for serializer
new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some of the comments the *safest* approach would be to implement an interface that encompasses all the types that you might expect to be stored in that object and use `TypeNameHandling.Auto`.

However, you could change data to be of type **dynamic** instead of object. This should persist the typing info as long as TypeNameHandling is turned on. And Json.NET will use that for deserialization as well. This assumes that the objects you store are serializable. This does not require any converters.

Also, you will see a lot of warnings about using TypeNameHandling. If you are in control of the JSON at all times and aren't worried about ill-intended actors it shouldn't be a concern. But turning on TypeNameHandling for deserialization opens up a door to insert potentially malicious code into your application since you're giving Json.NET free reign to create any type of object in your assemblies.

Comment: Thanks for your insights.

Saving/storing happens server side, this is just to get the object into a db row. I did origninally wanted to design this so that simple types could also be given directly (`Data = 32L;`) but if i'd wrap it into a class and use an interface it'd be better.